# Error 1044 access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I just installed Wampserver and I'm trying to create a new database but once I type a name for it and click create, I get this error "#1044 - access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database".
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

When you login to MySQL, phpMyAdmin you have to use a real account.

WampServer sets the `root` account up without a password, so

Use `Username` = root

And leave `Password` = [blank]

> Also WAMPServer installs both `MySQL` and `mariaDB`. Both are actually activated by default, so either disable the one you dont want to use (and switch the other to use port 3306) Or make sure you select the correct DBMS in the dropdown on the `phpMyAdmin` login page

Comment: Actually I can login but that's not the problem. The problem is when I click on Database icon and there is a field for the name of database. But after entering the name I click on create button and then  get the error

Comment: But your error message has NO USER in the `'^^^ This is user field and its blank ^^^'@'localhost'`

Comment: phpMyAdmin can make it appear like its logged in, but because there is no valid account used at login, its not logged in and when you attempt to do anything it fails

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: Did you login using `root` as the Username?

Comment: Yes, also I left the password field empty and I solved the problem by changing the server from a specific name that I can't remember to MySql and it worked and the databse was created but I have a new problem.

Comment: was it mariaDB? That name you cannot remember

Comment: I did login through the root username and empty password and solved the problem by changing the server from MariaDB to MySQL. But now there is a new problem.When I try to get wordpress access for my just created database by navigating "localhost/learnwordpress(my wordpress folder)/wp-admin" and entering the database name,username(which is root as you mentioned), password(blank),Database Host(localhost) and Table Prefix(wp_) , a  message is shown saying " can not select database " but I'm pretty sure that I typed the name of database correctly.